How to use previous prefetched data in RTK query when the query params got changed
I am using React with redux RTK query. I have an API to get Applications if student. By default, I am calling this api with rows per page 25 and prefetching 4 pages data in advance. So, I should have 25*4=100 data already prefetched.
Now, if the user changes the rows per from 25 to 50 or 100, I want to show those previous prefetched 100 data. for rows per page 50 it will be separated into 2 pages and for rows per page 100, it will show in one page.
Currently, if I am changing the rows per page from 25 to 50 or anything else, the API is getting called which I don't want if I have that amount of data already prefetched.
Here is my get application query code
getApplications: builder.query({
  query: ({
    pageNumber,
    rowsPerPage,
    collegeId,
    twelveScoreSort,
    payload,
    formInitiated,
  }) => ({
    url: `/admin/all_applications/${
      formInitiated ? "?form_initiated=false&" : "?"
    }page_num=${pageNumber}&page_size=${rowsPerPage}${
      twelveScoreSort === true || twelveScoreSort === false
        ? "&twelve_score_sort=" + twelveScoreSort
        : ""
    }${collegeId ? "&college_id=" + collegeId : ""}`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get(
        "jwtTokenCredentialsAccessToken"
      )}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: payload,
  }),
  keepUnusedDataFor: Infinity,
  providesTags: ["updateApplications"],
})


You might look into customizing your query cache key(s) and manually updating the cache so all paginated results are cached more efficiently.
